# Is it possible to upgrade only DateTime Library PHP

Tags: php, datetime, upgrade

While using some of the DateTime Function's at local machine ,later i founded out that our Server has 5.2.x while i had 5.3.x in my local machine.

Is it possible to upgrade only the DateTime Library to act like 5.3.x because we have some App's which might not work in php 5.3.x.

Bests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime is not a library, it is a part of PHP core: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.requirements.php

So it is impossible.

What feature do you need exactly?

Comment: Well the missing Features are ,DateTime::createFromFormat ,DateTime::add ,DateTime::diff etc.

Comment: This is kind of ugly, but this comment has a solution: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#96875. I would consider upgrading php/moving to a different hosting.

Comment: thanks a lot matte ,but moving to another Server is hard because we have ton of app's there and im not sure if they're supported on 5.3.x !

Comment: Here is a list of backward-incompatibilities: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php I'd say it is not a lot, and getting rid of magic quotes(if they are used in your apps) would be a plus.